# no menu error 500 after upgrade to 5.8.x

Tags: menu

On Ubuntu 18.04, apache 2.4.29 all patches for both applied.
Did an upgrade today to 5.8.0. The header civi nav menu isn't displaying. 
Installed 5.8.1 to make sure it wasn't something cooky, still no menu.

I've checked permissions for WP. I've checked that the path to the file is kosher, and it exists just fine. I've done the cache and path reset inside civi.

Error log in apache shows:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method CRM_Core_SelectValues::quicksearchOptions() in /home/folder/domains/secure.folder.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/AJAX.php:60
Stack trace:
#0 /home/folder/domains/secure.folder.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/AJAX.php(49): CRM_Admin_Page_AJAX::getSearchOptions()
#1 /home/folder/domains/secure.folder.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(275): CRM_Admin_Page_AJAX::getNavigationMenu()
#2 /home/folder/domains/secure.folder.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array)
#3 /home/folder/domains/secure.folder.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array)
#4 /home/folder/domains/secure.folder.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1240): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)
#5 /home/folder/domains/secure.folder.org/public_html/wp-includes/class-w in /home/folder/domains/secure.folder.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/AJAX.php on line 60, 
referer: https://secure.narsol.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Andy. Welcome to civicrm stack exchange. That function is new in 5.8.x . As a first step I would try clearing your caches as you indicate you have (sometimes doing it twice helps), and delete everything from your templates_c folder just in case.   (To find the templates_c folder head to /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fpath&reset=1 click on the blue arrow in the info box at the top of the page and not the location of the token [civicrm.files] in the popup.

Comment: @LukeStewart This is an acceptable answer!

Answer (score 4):

Andy, Welcome to CiviCRM stack exchange.

This is a weird error, since this function is already present in CiviCRM 5.8.1. But to trace the problem I would

1. Check if the function quicksearchOptions() exists in civicrm/CRM/Core/SelectValues.php.
2. Check if this file is being over-ridden by any of the extension or custom php
3. Check if civicrm/CRM/Core/SelectValues.php file is being invoked.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: I agree with Pradeep and Luke.  If this isn't a matter of a caching issue, that sure smells like an incompatible extension.